# Join no SQL com duas tabelas - usuarios e células

Tags: sql, join, chave-composta

Eu tenho duas tabelas no meu banco de dados, uma contendo todos os usuários com id e nome e demais detalhes, e uma outra tabela contendo todas as células de trabalho, onde amarro através do id de usuário quem é o líder e quem é o supervisor na célula.

Cada célula tem 1 líder e 1 supervisor, ambos os campos (colunas na tabela de células) possuem como valor o número do índice numérico que faz referencia a tabela de usuarios (chave estrangeira que identifica o usuário líder, e o usuário que é o supervisor da célula).

Para saber portanto quem é o líder da célula, usaria o valor armazenado na coluna leader_id, como chave de busca na tabela users. E o mesmo para supervisor (usando o campo supervisor_id como chave de busca na tabela users).

As tabelas estão como mostrado abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de criar uma pesquisa SQL que retorne o resultado da seguinte forma, usando os valores destas duas tabelas como parâmetro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar com esta pesquisa SQL?

Comment: podemos ajudar, pode mostrar até onde conseguiu chegar com a query?

Comment: Eu consegui fazer esta query: SELECT * FROM cells
INNER JOIN users ON cells.leader_id = users.id; Porém, eu estou conseguindo apenas retornar uma das colunas (ou usando o leader_id ou o supervisor_id como referencia apenas). Porém no resultado eu preciso da coluna com o nome do líder e do supervisor, pois vou passar o resutado da query para uma view no Laravel...

Comment: Utilize dois JOIN com a mesma tabela users, um para obter o lider e outro para obter o supervisor.

Answer (score 2):

Como o @anonimo comentou, basta adicionar um novo `join` para a mesma tabela, porém usando a coluna "supervisor_id":

```
SELECT cells.Cell_ID,
       UserLeader.name AS Leader,
       UserSuper.name AS Supervisor
  FROM cells 
 INNER JOIN users UserLeader ON cells.leader_id = UserLeader.id
 INNER JOIN users UserSuper  ON cells.supervisor_id = UserSuper.id
```

Comment: Obrigado @Ricardo Pontual pela query e pelo apoio!!

Comment: Testei agora e funcionou perfeitamente, exatamente o que eu precisava!

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi útil, dê um UP e, se estiver correta, marque-a como tal! Veja [Porque é importante votar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).